# Replacing row of table with a view

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am generating table like that:

```html
<div class="table zebra-striped selectable">
    {{#each "App.accidentsController.content"}}
        {{view App.AccidentView contentBinding="this"}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

where `App.AccidentView` is something like this:

```html
<div {{action tbodyClick this target='this'}} class="tr accident">
    <div class="td w03pr">{{unbound [1]}}</div>
    <div class="td">{{unbound [3]}}</div>
    <div class="td">{{unbound [4]}}</div>
</div>
```

I am considering performance issues as number of rows there might be hundreds or even thousands so I am not using binding for rows and at the moment not considering `ContainerView` seriously (or should I?). After I manipulated with row data I just want to replace all row's html. I have a row template and context of it and I think most simple and effective way would be just replace a row html with new one and I can do as per documentation something like this:

```js
var newView=App.AccidentView.create(newContext);
newView.appendTo('div.table');
```

But `append` is not enough there I need it to be placed instead of old row - something like jQuery's replaceWith. So my question is what is proper way of doing this - somehow to trim `tr` tags of view or use `ContainerView` but what about perfomance then? Thanks for any insights.

Comment: 1. Could you please clarify, why do you need to replace all row's html after operation with a single row? 2. Why do you want to use a `ContainerView`, and not simply a `View`?

Comment: @s.ermakovich 1. Content changed there and there is smth embeded for search capabilities. I have a template of whole row so I have to insert view before or after old row and then remove old one. I can't insert into it (`appendTo`) - I'd get illegal html.  2. ContainerView has mechanism for adding/removing views. But it seems to heavy for this case.

Comment: 1. Not sure that understand the case. 2. As far as i know, `ContainerView` is suitable, when you have some composition, and want to display multiple views inside of a single view. If I understand correctly, for displaying a single view, backed with a template, a simple `View` will be enough. `ContainerView` will also work, but it will be probably less lightweight (something, that you definitely want to avoid).